Sieve filtering - "body" extension not working as expected
I am attempting to write a Sieve email filter using the "body", "regex", and "variables" extensions.
Following is a very simplified version of the filter to test/demonstrate:
require ["body", "regex", "variables", "vnd.cyrus.log"];

if allof (
   address :is "from" "no_reply@yabbadabba.doo",
   body :regex "message from ([0-9]+) to 456:(.+)"
) {
   log "1 = \"${1}\"";
   log "2 = \"${2}\"";
}

And following is a very simple raw test message:
To: fred@theflintston.es
Subject: New message from 123 to 456
From: <no_reply@yabbadabba.doo>

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

message from 123 to 456:hello world

Testing this filter with the very handy sieve tester at (https://app.fastmail.com/sievetester) results in the following output:
sieve log: text=1 = ""
sieve log: text=2 = ""
keeping message

I am expecting the output to be:
sieve log: text=1 = "123"
sieve log: text=2 = "hello world"
keeping message

Why do $1 and $2 variables not get set?

First, make sure any regex works for you. Like message(.*). If it does not work, make sure there are no typos before regex calling code. Check address :is "from" "no_reply@yabbadabba.doo", - are you sure there are no typos there?

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78377453/sieve-filter-script-regex it is exactly what your'e problem is

Wow, @redoc thank you so much.
